# How to use TeleTalk internet in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, internet

I's using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed TeleTalk (with TeleTalk dongle modem) for Internet. Then I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the UI of TeleTalk is not functioning.

How can I use TeleTalk Internet Modem in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it incidentally :)

From the Network Icon:

- I choose "Edit Connections"
- Then clicked "Add"
- Choose "Mobile Broadband" from the dropdown menu
- Then choose "ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM" from the dropdown menu (May be it's listed because the modem was inserted)
- Then choose my country "Bangladesh"
- But the operator was not in the list, so I checked the radio button for "Can't find..." and inserted "TeleTalk" manually.
- Then choose "My Plan is not listed"
- Below there's a field for APN (Access Point Name). Contact with TeleTalk for the APN and insert it here. Insert "wap" there.

I'm using TeleTalk internet from my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, and posting the Q&A here. :)

Comment: I can't found "ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM" see the screenshot https://pasteboard.co/GWmxdZl.png I can call using the modem now, but can't use internet.

Comment: see my modem connection https://pasteboard.co/GWmzHJx.png

Answer (score 0):

you have to install network manager and wvdial. then ubuntu 16.04 will automatically detect it. if not then eject modem from unity launcher by right clikcing on modem drive and then eject.